# Python sqlite3 - operationalerror near "2017"

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm new to programming. I have `dictionary` called record, that receives various inputs like 'Color', 'Type' 'quantity',etc. Now I tried to add a Date column then insert into sqlite table running through the 'if loop' with the code below. But I get an "Operational error near 2017", ie near the date.

Can anyone help please? Thanks in advance

```
Date = str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

record['Date'] = Date

column = [record['Color'], Date]

values = [record['quantity'], record['Date']]

column = ','.join(column)  

if record['Type'] == 'T-Shirts' and record['Style'] == 'Soft':

    stment = ("INSERT INTO xtrasmall (%s) values(?)" %column)
    c.execute(stment, values)
    conn.commit()
```

Comment: See http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated**

You can simplify the code as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime

date = datetime.now().date() 
sql = "INSERT INTO xtrasmall (%s, Date) values (?, ?)" % record['Color']
c.execute(sql, (record['quantity'], date))
```

This substitutes the value of the selected color directly into the column names in the query string. Then the query is executed passing the quantity and date string as arguments. The date should automatically be converted to a string, but you could convert with `str()` if desired.

This does assume that the other colour columns have a default value (presumably 0), or permit null values.

---

**Original answer**

Because you are constructing the query with string interpolation (i.e. substituting `%s` for a string) your statement becomes something like this:

```
INSERT INTO xtrasmall (Red,2017-10-06) values(?)
```

which is not valid because `2017-10-06` is not a valid column name. Print out `stment` before executing it to see.

If you know what the column names are just specify them in the query:

```
values = ['Red', 2, Date]
c.execute("INSERT INTO xtrasmall (color, quantity, date) values (?, ?, ?)", values)
conn.commit()
```

You need to use a `?` for each column that you are inserting.

---

It looks like you want to insert the dictionary using its keys and values. This can be done like this:

```
record = {'date':'2017-10-06', 'color': 'Red', 'quantity': 2}

columns = ','.join(record.keys())
placeholders = ','.join('?' * len(record.values()))
sql = 'INSERT INTO xtrasmall ({}) VALUES ({})'.format(columns, placeholders)
c.execute(sql, record.values())
```

This code will generate the parameterised SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO xtrasmall (date,color,quantity) VALUES (?,?,?)
```

and then execute it using the dictionary's values as the parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And I get your explanation. I had printed it out to see how it looked like. But the column names are a drop down list in a tkinter gui app. So depending on which name is selected, it gets inserted into the table with the date, hence the string interpolation. Is there a way around it?

Comment: @TBright: the second half of my answer should help you with that. You will need to take care that all of the required columns are selected in the UI.

Comment: I've tried that but it didn't work. My table has only a date column and the remaining columns are colors. The entry fields in the table is the quantity that will be received from the UI, then it looks for the particular color selected and saves it under that column with the Date. when I tried your answer, it attempted looking for columns that are not in my table.

Comment: Thanks so much. Your answer helped. I've resolved it